# Creating a local storage directory in Java desktop app

Tags: java, desktop-application

I'm building a Java desktop application and need to store some local data (preferences and history). For this I'd like to create a new folder in the appropriate location, like *AppData\myapp* in Windows and *~/.myapp* in Linux (and wherever is expected on a Mac).

What is the nice, cross-platform way to do that?

---

I've seen several questions on this site that ask about this, but either:

- The asker wants to find Windows' *Application Data* (not cross-platform)
- The solution is to create a folder in `user.home` (Linux style, not cross-platform) This is what I currently do, but I'm looking for an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the [Java Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) which will store info per-user and you don't have to worry about the implementation. Different implementations are available for different platforms but that's hidden from you (the client).

An alternative is to use the [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html) API, which is more complex, but gives you a lot more features.

Comment: That might be a good place for preferences as he says, but history data should probably not be there.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't seem to fit entirely, but interesting nonetheless. I didn't know of this API.

Comment: I guess the question around history may depend on how *much* history. Both APIs will have the capability, but perhaps some load testing is in order

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;

public class AppPathFolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = null;
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (osName.indexOf("windows")>-1) {
            path = System.getenv("APPDATA");
        } else if (osName.indexOf("mac")>-1) {
            // get the env. variable for Mac..
            path = System.getenv("?");
            // etc. for Linux, Unix, Solaris..
        } else { //anything else
            path = System.getProperty("user.home");
        }
        File rootOfPath = new File(path);
        // create a sub-directory based on package name of main class..
        // perhaps prefixed with with java/appdata
        System.out.println(rootOfPath);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are other options for small amounts of data:

- Apps. that are trusted or have no security manager might use the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API
- A desktop app. launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) has access to the JNLP API, wich offers the `PersistenceService` - available even to sand-boxed apps.
- An applet can store cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Use `user.home` system property. Like this:

```
String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
File myAwesomeFolder = new File(useHomePath, "myAweSomeApp");
myAwesomeFolder.mkdirs();
```

Comment: I've tested that on Windows 7 where it returns `C:\User\John`, whereas I probably want `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local`

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom, well, that's because it returns your `home` folder, not `AppData`.

Comment: `user.home` is a place that is guaranteed to be writable, and is x-plat.  Maybe you can use an environment variable where known and `user.home` otherwise.

Comment: @npe So it doesn't return what I need, does it? ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Using the APPDATA environment var might work, yes. Why don't you put it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the app-folder into the user home directory? You can get it per System.getProperty("user.home"), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: See question and npe's answer

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when I was finished dropping my answer.

Answer (score -1):

not confirmed about Linux but you can make entry to windows registry too.

either way,

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\AppLication Data"+"\\xyzFolder";
```

this works for both windows 7 to because %appData% shows the path which legacy for above.

Comment: This is anything but cross-platform.